# How to do ajax form post while page load after submit a form in symfony2

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, post

I have to retain drop down value and also some specific data according to the drop down selection.

Normally its working fine for me but i need same thing after submit a form (save the data), after save i need to retain the same.

Please advice about this or any other solution already having?

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I got solution end of the day so much tried.....